# Socket Exception: connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In our application, we are using docker container to run the web services.

When I am trying to connect to web services, sometimes I am getting the following error.

> **An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer.**

**Stack Trace**

```
Exception: at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) 
at MyLib.HttpHelper.HttpClientHelper.InternalRequestAsync(RequestContext requestContext) 
at MyLib.HttpHelper.HttpClientHelper.RequestAsync[T](RequestContext requestContext) Inner Exception: 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error) 
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync() 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ReadNextResponseHeaderLineAsync(Boolean foldedHeadersAllowed) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I went through many threads but that doesn't help.

Could you please suggest how to look further into that?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to elaborate more. It's could be when your ports are not configured correctly.  Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543787/docker-mule-server-curl-56-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer/26553296#26553296?

Comment: @Imran, I guess there is no issues in ports configuration, Since We are facing this issue intermittently. Once in 500 requests.

Comment: Hi @Nagalakshmi , Are you able to solve this issue